# Java thread and synchronised methods not performing as required

Tags: java, android, multithreading, thread-safety, runnable

I am trying since 2 days continuously and already referred many SO questions and answers on related issue.

**The Context :**

1. The Runnable class gets multiple calls from another service class.
2. Runnable class must finish already running and synchronised method before starting it again

**Calling Runnable threads from a service :**

```
final Singular_Processor singularProcessor = new Singular_Processor(this);
singularProcessor.start();
synchronized(singularProcessor.context)
{
     while(singularProcessor.needWait)
     {
          wait();
     }
}
```

**Actual Runnable thread class :**

```
class Singular_Processor extends Thread
{
    private static final String TAG = "Singular_Processor";
    final Context context;
    boolean needWait = false;

    Singular_Processor(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            doNotDisturbMe();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void doNotDisturbMe()
    {
        synchronized (context)
        {
            try
            {
                needWait = true;
                Log.d(TAG, "RUNNING THE THREAD ID : " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + ".. \n");
                Thread.sleep(10000);
                Log.d(TAG, "COMPLETED THE THREAD ID : " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + ".. \n");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d(TAG, "EXCEPTION THE THREAD ID : " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + ".. \n");
            }
            finally
            {
                needWait = false;
                context.notifyAll();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**What is expected output :**

```
2020-12-30 17:55:46.519 30184-30398/ D/Singular_Processor: RUNNING THE THREAD ID : 6053.. 
2020-12-30 17:55:50.474 30184-30455/ D/Singular_Processor: COMPLETED THE THREAD ID : 6053..
2020-12-30 17:55:56.520 30184-30398/ D/Singular_Processor: RUNNING THE THREAD ID : 6056..
2020-12-30 17:56:00.475 30184-30455/ D/Singular_Processor: COMPLETED THE THREAD ID : 6056..
```

**What is current output :**

```
2020-12-30 17:55:46.519  D/Singular_Processor: RUNNING THE THREAD ID : 6053.. 
2020-12-30 17:55:50.474  D/Singular_Processor: RUNNING THE THREAD ID : 6056.. 
2020-12-30 17:55:56.520  D/Singular_Processor: COMPLETED THE THREAD ID : 6053.. 
2020-12-30 17:56:00.475  D/Singular_Processor: COMPLETED THE THREAD ID : 6056..
```

**Are there any errors :**

Not at all as everything is syntax wise correct. Why android can not wait for few seconds before completing the already running and synchronised method on full locked object of thread class context, is worrying me. I hope i get some idea here on SO. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

If you launch `Singular_Processor` from the same service you need to make `needWait` shared between all `Singular_Processor` threads. One of the possible solution is to place it in the service itself, because you synchronize on the same context and use `needWait` that is a field of different instances of `Singular_Processor` class.

Comment: Dear the link you provided on standard java synchronizers, if i implement it, it will block the main service for 20 seconds and my service is a broadcast receiver, android allows a broadcast receivers to run maximum of 5 seconds

Comment: And i am not launching Singular_Processor twice, its natural java tendency of threading, it spawns new one as thread

Comment: What tendency are you talking about? You start a thread only once but in the logs, you have two different threads. That means that `Singular_Processor ` is launched twice.

Comment: I edited the answer, sorry, I didn't understand the real problem.

Comment: I can not place { needWait } in service as service is a broadcast receiver which stopSelf itself multiple times on which { needWait } will not be guranteed to be available every time. One way witch { ATOMIC needWait } within Runnable but it also did not worked as required

Comment: Tendency i am talking is if we call multiple time the runnable thread then java virtual machine which is multithreading capable runs every thread request with different thread id and every thread running carries exact copy of runnable class every thread has its own redudant copy of it but a separate one.

Comment: Will you please look at  :  What is expected output :???

Comment: I saw the expected output but you cannot achieve it with the code you provided because you are not sharing the state between the threads. To help this issue I am going to need more information such is why you even need to wait for 10 seconds in the broadcast receiver.

Comment: Check i have posted answer, I am all done as expected and thanks a lot for giving your valuable time to help me out, thanks a lot bro

Comment: I see it, yeah that will work. But if you run it in a broadcast receiver the main thread will be blocked for 10 seconds since broadcast receivers run in the main thread.

Comment: Intent service, threads, runnables threads never runs on UI Thread, Service, Classes, Foreground Service, Broadcasr receivers does run on UI thread

Answer (score 0):

A Thread.sleep() does not release the sync lock. See its javadoc:

```
The thread does not lose ownership of any monitors.
```

Thus, only one thread may ever enter into your synchronized block(s).

Comment: Look now it does, I mean it has to, You can cross check running on your own compiler too. lol. I am happy though for your time you given to help me out. Thanks bro. great times ahead

Answer (score 0):

Posting answer to own question for the future visitors to this question on SO

**The Thread class :**

```
class Singular_Processor extends Thread
{
    private static final String TAG = "Singular_Processor";
    final Context context;

    Singular_Processor(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "run: starting " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + ".. \n");
            doNotDisturbMe();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static synchronized void doNotDisturbMe()
    {
        try
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "RUNNING THE THREAD ID : " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + ".. \n");
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            Log.d(TAG, "COMPLETED THE THREAD ID : " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + ".. \n");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d(TAG, "EXCEPTION THE THREAD ID : " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + ".. \n");
        }
    }
}
```

**Calling scenario :**

No matter you are starting a single thread or multiple threads at any intervals of time at any frequency and from anywhere from your project.. like from a broadcast receiver in my case as follows -

```
final Singular_Processor singularProcessor = new Singular_Processor(this);
singularProcessor.start();
```

No matter how many times above lines gets called and how many number of instances of that thread gets created..

1. As a `static method` is never created for specific instance of a class nor for thread instance too.
2. As i have created `static synchronised` all the thread instances will come to run method of their own instance and gets shocked, ooh the method i am calling is static and synchronised too.
3. Individual `threads are so smart and intelligent` enough that i even not required `wait` any one nor to bother about `notify` any one nor `notify all`

**Expected output :**

```
2020-12-30 22:31:07.856 7866-8309/MyPackage D/Singular_Processor: run: starting 7014.. 
2020-12-30 22:31:07.856 7866-8309/MyPackage D/Singular_Processor: RUNNING THE THREAD ID : 7014.. 
2020-12-30 22:31:11.285 7866-8389/MyPackage D/Singular_Processor: run: starting 7016.. 
2020-12-30 22:31:17.857 7866-8309/MyPackage D/Singular_Processor: COMPLETED THE THREAD ID : 7014.. 
2020-12-30 22:31:17.858 7866-8389/MyPackage D/Singular_Processor: RUNNING THE THREAD ID : 7016.. 
2020-12-30 22:31:27.859 7866-8389/MyPackage D/Singular_Processor: COMPLETED THE THREAD ID : 7016..
```